# Use definition to prove that the function $f(x,y)=xye^{xy}$ is differentiable at all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Use definition to prove that the function $f(x,y)=xye^{xy}$ is differentiable at all points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I tried to solve this question like so:-

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be any point in $\mathbb R^2$

$$\begin{aligned}
f_x&=y(e^{xy}+xe^{xy}y) \qquad\text{and} \qquad &f_{y}&=x(e^{xy}+ye^{xy}x)\\
   &=ye^{xy}+xy^2e^{xy}                         &     &=xe^{xy}+x^2ye^{xy}\end{aligned}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{aligned}
f_x(x_0,y_0)=y_0e^{x_0y_0}+x_0y_0^2e^{x_0y_0} \qquad\text{and} \qquad f_y(x_0,y_0)=x_0e^{x_0y_0}+x_0^2y_0e^{x_0y_0}\end{aligned}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{aligned}\Delta f(x_0,y_0)&=f(x_0+\Delta x,y_0+\Delta y) - f(x_0,y_0)\\
                                  &=(x_0y_0+x_0\Delta y + y_0\Delta x+\Delta x\Delta y)e^{x_0y_0+x_0\Delta y + y_0\Delta x+\Delta x\Delta y}-x_0y_0e^{x_0y_0}\qquad\small{\text{(By Substitution)}}\end{aligned}$$

And hence, I am not able to form them as

$$\Delta f(x_0,y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0)\Delta x+f_y(x_0,y_0)\Delta y+\epsilon_1\Delta x+\epsilon_2\Delta y$$

Sorry if it's really simple but I cannot figure a way how I can do it.

The definition mentioned in the question is as below:-

If $f$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$ and the increment of $f$ at $(a,b)$ $\left(\text{i.e.} \Delta f(a,b)=f_x(a,b)\Delta x + f_y(a,b)\Delta y + \epsilon_1\Delta x + \epsilon_2\Delta y\right)$ where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$are functions of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ such that $\epsilon_1 \to 0$ and $\epsilon_2\to0$ as $(\Delta x,\Delta y)\to(0,0)$, then function $f$ is said to be $\underline{\text{differentiable}}$ at $(a,b).$

Comment: Since you mention the definition in your post, can you please recall for us your definition of differentiable at a point for a function on $\mathbb R^2$? As fundamental a notion as this is, there are various equivalent definitions, so it will help people who want to answer your question to know which one you are using. Welcome to Math SE!

Comment: Definition added to the bottom @AlexOrtiz

Comment: Your definition  of  differentiability is somewhat strange. It seems to based on the partial derivatives.

Comment: This is the only definition I know right now @PaulFrost

Comment: @PaulFrost The definition quoted in the post is quite standard.

Comment: @coffeemath I do not doubt its correctness, but I have not seen it as a *definition*. Could you give a reference to some textbook?

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't have a specific reference book. I'm sorry

Comment: @PaulFrost See the text "Multivariate Calculus: concepts and contexts" by James Stewart, second edition, page 782 definition 7 at page bottom. I saw the same in some other calc texts.

Comment: @PaulFrost It occurred to me there are now a lot of editions of the above text. I found if one googles "multivariate calculus pdf" one of the first things that comes up is a pdf of Stewart's text I mentioned but it's 7th edition. So likely the page reference for the definition I gave doesn't correlate. Maybe the section does, it was in section 11.4 in 2nd ed. When I clicked, it seemed to take a long time to load (I aborted), but you may be able to get it that way, I didn't wait to see if a pay wall came up.